# Jquery click event not firing on relative input

Tags: jquery, css, firefox

Jquery

```
$(document).on("click","[type=text]",function(event) {
 alert('test');
});
```

CSS

```
.noWorking:focus{
 z-index:100;
 position:relative;
 outline:none;
 box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

I need a `z-index:100;` to make the shadow on top of all other elements. I also need a click event to work my input. In firefox, only double clicks fire events.

https://jsfiddle.net/oz68Lgcd/

Why do only double clicks in firefox fire events with relatively positioned inputs?

Comment: I get the alert for both inputs in the fiddle. I'm using Chrome.

Comment: I'm using firefox. But yes, I just checked and chrome works.

Comment: Does it work if you use normal event binding instead of delegation?

Comment: If you set `.noWorking { position:relative;}` it is fine

Comment: Perfect.  Works now.

Comment: @epascarello why not give it as answer :)

Comment: I wonder also if putting the element type `input` in the selector works: `$(document).on("click","input[type=text]",function(event) {`  It should also be more efficient than just the property attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the position from the default value to relative is throwing off Firefox appears. If you set it to relative by default the click works.

```
.noWorking { 
    position : relative; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello dear please use mousedown event instead of click event

```
$(document).on("mousedown", "input[type='text']", function(event) {
    alert('test');
});
```